Folium keep_in_front not working for TileLayer when mixed with other layer types
I am trying to add the TileLayer for the map labels on top of other overlays in Folium. The keep_in_front command keeps the labels on top of the other TileLayers, but not on top of the other overlays (of png images) or GeoJson.
#Get raster size and position
driver=gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
driver.Register()
ds = gdal.Open('/home/XXXX/Desktop/test.tif') 

#Get coordinates, cols and rows
geotransform = ds.GetGeoTransform()
cols = ds.RasterXSize 
rows = ds.RasterYSize 

#Get extent
xmin=geotransform[0]
ymax=geotransform[3]
xmax=xmin+cols*geotransform[1]
ymin=ymax+rows*geotransform[5]

#Get Central point
centerx=(xmin+xmax)/2
centery=(ymin+ymax)/2

#Prepare visualisation in Folium
#Visualization in Folium
b_tiles = folium.raster_layers.TileLayer(
    tiles='https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', 
    attr=('&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">'
        'OpenStreetMap</a> contributors &copy; <a '
        'href="https://carto.com/attributions">CARTO</a>'),
    control=False, maxZoom=20, subdomains='abcd')

m = folium.Map(location=[centery, centerx], zoom_start=8, tiles=b_tiles)

#Add raster information -- The raster has been previously exported as image
folium.raster_layers.ImageOverlay(
    image='/home/XXXX/Desktop/test.png',
    bounds=[[ymin, xmin], [ymax, xmax]], 
    name=d, control=True, show=True)) #(d == dates[-1])).add_to(m)

#Add city labels on top
labels = folium.raster_layers.TileLayer(
    tiles='https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_only_labels/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png',
        attr=('&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">'
            'OpenStreetMap</a> contributors &copy; <a 
            href="https://carto.com/attributions">CARTO</a>'), 
        name='labels', overlay=True, control=True, subdomains='abcd', maxZoom=20)
labels.add_to(m)

#Keep labels in front
m.keep_in_front(labels)

How can I make sure that the labels for the map show on top of all other layers?

The solution for this is to create a Custom Pane and pass the TileLayer with the labels to the pane through the "pane" argument. The Custom Pane will keep it on top of other layers.
#Add custom pane to display the labels on top
c_pane = folium.map.CustomPane(name='labels_pane', z_index=625)
c_pane.add_to(m)

#Add city labels on top
labels = folium.raster_layers.TileLayer(
    tiles='https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_only_labels/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png',
        attr=('&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">'
            'OpenStreetMap</a> contributors &copy; <a 
            href="https://carto.com/attributions">CARTO</a>'), 
        name='labels', overlay=True, control=True, subdomains='abcd', maxZoom=20, 
    pane="labels_pane")
labels.add_to(m)

